# Why jets entrain mass?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

[image]

This very beautiful picture shows a jet of fuel in the combustion chamber of a diesel engine. Does anydody could explain me what is the physical reason that the jet entrains air? Why jets and plumes entrain mass from the environment? 
Edit. I believe it has to do with the conservation of momentum and i always wait for the happy day when people will stop mentioning the Bernoulli equation.

Comment: what is the physical reason that the jet entrains air? Any high velocity movement of droplets  will create a low pressure due to Bernoulli principle (viscosity)and the air will rush from all sides.

Comment: @dvrm It is definitely not the Bernoulli principle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your many questions shows remarkable effort on questioning. You seem to note the point.

> Does anydody could explain me what is the physical reason that the jet entrains **air**?

**"Diffusion"** is now given as an answer. But If that would be true, a lot of air would be diffused also on the diesel stored in the tank. But there this doesn't happend in 10 years. [This video on 14:00->](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_oyqLOqwnI)

**"Celerity"** is nothing else [than saying it happends fast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celerity). But why should it happen fast?

I bolded "air" on your question. You are seeking the solution for Turbulence. I mostly avoid linking [this paper of mine here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/283451471_Turbulence), as it's not Mainstream Physics; Mainstream Physics can't explain turbulence. I would also like to link you these [videos of mine](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLgUc9kJnDMMExJivT2dWh9dAjdYYUgOFE). As it seems that you are able to ask you through this, up to the solution.

Turbulence is fluid Split in parts. Surfaces inside a fluid. Cracks which aloud the air to be Entrained. These cracks are caused by the **"friction"** this part of the first answer is correct. I rather use word collision. Look the Prince Rubert drops video in my playlist. And you sure find a certain **celerity.**

Answer (score 2):

By friction along the jet then diffusion of the celerity.

Comment: What do you mean when you write " diffusion of celerity "